# Difference between using lm + Arima and auto.arima

Tags: r, regression, arima

I want to do a linear regression over the corporate spread bonds. The way I did it is to run a linear model using `lm`, then running an `auto.arima` on residuals of the output of `lm` and at last use the same coefficients as in the `auto.arima` and run an `Arima` model with the spread values. At last, I want to do a forecast. When I run an `auto.arima` with xreg, I get a different answer from using `lm`+`Arima`.  I get an "I" term when using `auto.arima` though my variables are all stationary. I wonder what is the correct way to do this.
Here's my code:

```
forecast.func <- function(NS.spread, ind.v, maturity, training, forc.horizon){
  
  NS.spread <- NS.spread/100
  forc <- list()
  j <- 0
  
  for(i in 1:floor((nrow(NS.spread)-training)/forc.horizon)){
    
    # linear model
    y <- as.vector(NS.spread[(1+j):(training+j) , maturity])
    f <- ind.v[(1+j):(training+j) , maturity]
    a <- cbind(y,f)
    a <- as.data.frame(a)
    b <- lm(y ~ lagmatrix(f, -1), data= a)
    
    
    # auto- arima
    c <- auto.arima(b$residuals, test= "adf")
    
    # Arima
    d <- Arima(y, xreg = lagmatrix(f, -1), order = c(c$arma[1], c$arma[6], c$arma[2]), include.mean = FALSE)
    
    # forecast
    e <- ind.v[(training+j+1):(training+j+forc.horizon) , maturity]
    h <- forecast(d, xreg = lagmatrix(e, -1))
    
    forc <- c(h, forc)
    
    j <- j + forc.horizon

  }
  
  return(forc)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Difference between using `lm` + `Arima` and `auto.arima`

In `lm` + `Arima`, the `lm` estimates ignore the ARIMA structure of the error term. This yields a logical inconsistency; the `lm` step effectively assumes no ARIMA structure, but the next step explicitly models it. Both the point estimates and the confidence intervals from `lm` can be expected to differ from the case where the error structure is not ignored. This probably also explains the problem with the `I` term.

In `Arima` with `xreg` or `auto.arima` with `xreg`, the estimates of `xreg` take the ARIMA structure of the error term into account. This is the proper way to account for error autocorrelation.

Comment: Shouldn't `gls` used instead?

Comment: @usεr11852, perhaps it could. It depends on how the covariance matrix would be estimated. I would use maximum likelihood for estimating ARIMA-type models, including regression with ARIMA errors such as here. As long as the likelihood is well specified, it would be my method of choice due to all the nice properties of MLEs. If the likelihood is off, then GLS might be an interesting competitor. I wonder how the results would compare in practice given moderate violations of the distributional asssumption.

Comment: @usεr11852, also, while GLS would yield reasonable point estimates of slope coefficients, a lack of an explicit model of the error structure would prevent making accurate forecasts. This is another argument in favour of regression with ARIMA errors over GLS.

Comment: I was thinking somehting like`gls( ..., correlation=corARMA(p,q), method="ML")` so we fit a multivariate regression with autocorrelated errors. In that way after doing an `auto.arima(residuals(lm(...)))` we pass the relevant structure to `gls` so we go around the `lm` + `Arima` inconsistency.  (My bad, probably I should have written this out originally and not just "*`gls` would work, no?*" comment this.)

Comment: @usεr11852, OK, but I suppose this does not solve the problem of predictions that ignore the ARIMA structure aside from adjusting the slope coefficients in a sensible way. Also, I have long been confused by GLS implemented via maximum likelihood (though I have never put much effort into clarifying things for myself). Does that mean the covariance matrix is estimated by ML? If not, I am puzzled. For me, GLS is an estimation technique similar to OLS. When ML gets involved, might we be actually doing more or less the same as ML estimation of regression with ARIMA errors?

Comment: Yes, we would. I found `gls(method="ML", ...)` to give very similar results with `stats::arima()`

Comment: @usεr11852, precisely what do you mean by *results*? Slope estimates (point and interval)?

Comment: Slope point estimates; I cannot remember the intervals of the top of my head. I remember the AIC/BIC being very similar too so that also corroborates the point estimates being close.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for the explanation. So if I just do an ```auto.arima``` from the top with a ```xreg```, the model's structure would be correct? Also, what type of test do you recommend to use in the ```auto.arima```?

Comment: @AgatheSadeghi, yes, I would use `auto.arima` with `xreg`. What hypothesis would you like to test?

Comment: @RichardHardy I want my model to forecast correctly and not have any correlations between the error terms. I want to make sure they are white noise.

Comment: `auto.arima` will not necessarily select a model that has virtually no autocorrelations (say, at a 95% confidence level), but that is a good thing. You do not want a model like that, because it would likely overfit. Actually, moderate estimated autocorrelation is not likely to be a problem as trying to account for it may result ir overfitting. But this is actually a separate question, so consider posting it separately. Or actually, do not post it just yet; there are dozens of similar questions already asked and answered on this site. Search, and you will find some that should be helpful.

Comment: @AgatheSadeghi, I would rather look at some diagnostic plots but not necessarily use null hypothesis significance testing formally.